# Nullable column not behaving as such

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, mariadb

I have a table `actor` with a nullable column `first_name`. I set a specific row to null:

```
update actor set first_name=null where actor_id=201;
Query OK, 1 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
```

I then try to query that table using the null value in my where clause and get nothing back:

```
select * from actor where first_name is null;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

But if I select checking if that column is an empty string, I get the right value back:

```
select * from actor where first_name = '';
[...]
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Storage engine is MyISAM. Why is a nulled column being set to empty string?

**Update**

I see the 1 warning but mysql CLI does not show any warnings. How can I make it do so?

Also:

```
desc actor;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| actor_id    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| first_name  | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_name   | varchar(45)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| last_update | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Show us the `show create table actor` statement..

Comment: As `Warnings: 1` is there.So definitely it will suggest some error.

Comment: Note your query `update actor set first_name=null where actor_id=201;` generated a warning.`Query OK, 1 rows affected, 1 warning`  please also show us the warning with SHOW WARNINGS;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Table description, looks like all columns including first_name are not null. Are you sure it is nullable column?

Comment: I'm looking at the default value so you may be right. So updating to null sets it to empty string instead of returning an error?

Comment: Yeah, the rules are screwball.